# Which Magento 2 version to install

Tags: patches, version

I'm unfamiliar with the release cycles overall and want to install Magento but at the same time have some community extensions available. 
I've looked at the downloads page and ver 2.0.10 and ver 2.1.2 is available. If I installed the former ver 2.0.10 which version is next ? Is it ver 2.1.0 ?

Which is best that allows for additional extensions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 2 uses sementic versioning. This means that the version number is built like `<major>.<minor>.<patch>`.

That means that the next version of 2.0.10 will be 2.0.11.
The next version of 2.1.2 will be 2.1.3

Minor and Patch updates should always be backward compatible according to this model. Major versions don't need to be backward compatible.

But to answer you question: install the latest version and update regularly during development. There are still many bugs and unfinished features in Magento 2. It will work, but you need to keep it up to date for at least the next year.

My best guess for a real stable Magento will be when it hits version 2.2 or 2.3 at least.

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2 is a very new software, and new versions often contain not only new features, but also a lot of bugfixes and code-improvements.

You should always install the latest version, and Magento 2 extensions should always aim to be compatible with this latest version.

Comment: Is Magento 1.x still a valid choice for a new install ? I cannot find the link any longer.

Comment: Magento 1.x releases can be found under "Release Archive" on the magento.com download page. Depending on the complexity of the project, I would still consider Magento 1.x a valid choice.

Comment: For new projects I would not suggest Magento 1.9.x anymore. But that depends on your own Magento skillset, programming level and the complexity of your project. If you're solely dependant on external themes and plugins I would not suggest Magento 2 since that market is - like Magento 2 - not yet mature. However, delivering a product now that is build on a system that had it's last major release more than a year ago and is only getting patches is also questionable.